# Creating a buffer in ArcMap....?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I need to create a buffer around a polygon.

I know how to do this, but my problem is I need the buffer to be 250 feet to the south, east, and west, but 500 feet to the north.

Is there any way to specify the distance of a buffer in a certain direction from a feature?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188139/buffering-point-with-different-distance-toward-n-e-s-w-using-arcgis-for-deskt

Comment: Note that the above is not an exact solution, since that question was about a *point* buffer, but it could be used to inform a polygon solution (albeit with a good deal of effort)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great Q&A about it at [Creating buffer only in specific direction using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156927/how-to-set-a-buffer-only-in-a-specific-direction)

If you only have one polygon, you could do it manually by creating two sets of buffers.  one for 500 and one for 250.  You can extend the left and right sides of the 250 buffer polygon to the top/north part of the 500 polygon in an edit session.   This would be the quickest way if it's only the one polygon of course.